# Excel VBA to split PDF files

Tags: excel, vba

I have a PDF of 120 pages, I want to split this PDF according to the following image
[image]

In column B and C i have page from and to information it should split according to this. For example if it splits from page 1 to 6 and it should save as GI in column A this is possible in Excel VBA if it is possible can somebody say me how to split this PDF, I'm having adobe acrobat x1 pro.

with regards,
yuvaraj.

Comment: When you say "save as GI in column A" do you mean the newly created file should be "GI.pdf" ?

Comment: yes i have to  create file newly

Comment: can this is possible

Comment: If you have Acrobat Professional installed, you can use it as a reference like in http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1538892.

Comment: but this seems to be not working

Comment: This is not possible without Acrobat Professional.